# Understanding recursion in a function that converts list of Maybe a to Maybe [a]

Tags: haskell, recursion

While learning Haskell I came across this flipMaybe function:

```
flipMaybe :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]
flipMaybe [] = Just []
flipMaybe (Nothing:xs) = Nothing
flipMaybe (Just x:xs) = case flipMaybe xs of  
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just ls  -> Just (x:ls)
```

I can't wrap my head around the last line. What is `ls` here? How does the recursion work here? Or in another words, can someone show me how this function solves `flipMaybe [Just 1, Just 2, Just 3]`? (step by step)

Comment: `ls` is the data wrapped in a `Just` of the recursion, so if `flipMaybe [Just 2, Just 3]` is a `Just` (here `Just [2, 3]`, then `ls` is a list `[2, 3]` and this is thus prepended with `x`, and wrapped in a `Just`.

Comment: `flipMaybe [Just 1, Just 2, Just 3]` --> `case flipMaybe [Just 2, Just 3] of ...` --> `case Just [2, 3] of Nothing -> Nothing; Just ls -> Just (1: ls)` --> `Just (1:[2, 3])`

Comment: In other words, `Just ls` in the `case ... of ...` is pattern-matching, similar to the `Just x:xs` pattern-matching in the definition of `filpMaybe`. But this time, instead of doing pattern-matching on the input of the function, we're doing pattern-matching on the output of the recursive call `flipMaybe xs`

Comment: What you here implemented is a special case of [`sequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence) with `m ~ Maybe` and `t ~ []`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't wrap my head around the last line. What is `ls` here?

If the recursive call on the tail of the list return a `Just ls`, then `ls` is the list wrapped in the `Just`. So if `flipMaybe [Just 3]` is called, this will return a `Just [3]`, and thus `ls` is `[3]`.

This is used to prepend the list with `xs`. If we thus evaluate `flipMaybe [Just 1, Just 2]`, then we first inspect the first item, if that is a `Nothing`, we return `Nothing`: we do not care about the rest of the list, we know that the outcome will be a `Nothing`, if it is a `Just …`, we should check what `flipMaybe [Just 2]` will return. If it returns a `Nothing`, then we thus return `Nothing`, since then it means there is a `Nothing` in the tail of the list. If it is a `Just ls`, then we return a `Just (x : ls)`, we thus prepend the item of the list to the outcome of the recursive call.

If the list thus looks like `[Just 2, Nothing, Just 3]`, then we first investigate `Just 2`, since it is not `Nothing`, we make a recursive call with `flipMaybe [Nothing, Just 3]`. Since that list starts with a `Nothing`, `Nothing` is returned from the `flipMaybe [Nothing, Just 3]`, and thus we return `Nothing` for `flipMaybe [Just 2, Nothing, Just 3]`.